# Closed form of chi-square divergence between two gaussians

Tags: probability, statistics

If $f_1$ is the pdf of a $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $f_2$ is the pdf of a $N(\nu,\tau^2)$, can I compute the Chi Squared divergence between $f_1$ and $f_2$ in closed form (as a function of the parameters $\mu, \nu, \sigma^2,\tau^2$)? I've done it with the Kullback Leibler divergence without spending much time, but I can't do the same with the chi-squared.

@John:
I've tried to integrate directly $\int \frac{f_1^2}{f_2}dx-1$ or equivalently $\int \frac{{(f_1-f_2)}^2}{f_2}dx$ or $\int f_2 (\frac{f_1}{f_2}-1) dx$. All the problem is reconducible to integrate $\int e^{-(ax^2+bx+c)}dx$ for some $a,b,c$ but this integral does not converge for negative values of $a$. In my calculations, the coefficent $a$ is something like the difference of two variances, so it could be negative.

Answer (score 3):

By directly computing the integral, one obtains

$$
D_2 = \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\tau^2}{\sigma\sqrt{2\tau^2 - \sigma^2}}
    e^{\frac{(\mu-\nu)^2}{2\tau^2 - \sigma^2}} - 1
  \right).
$$

This expression is real if $\sigma^2 < 2\tau^2$. So, it seems the Chi Squared divergence is only defined for certain suitable pairs of Gaussians.